# split dataframe to multiples dataset

Tags: python, dataframe

I have dataframe which has indexed column and  ds_value column like printed df below

```
index   ds_value <br>
1       SEG1|CA|90025|34|~SEG2|2|3|10150|~TITLE|Test| <br>
2       SEG1|NV|90567|50|~SEG24|4|5|54678|~JOB|None|<br>
```

How can I find each segment type on each rows and split the segment type of the data row based on pipe delimited for each segment. Segment can be the same name or it can be difference name each segment separated by ~ charater
In this case, I have  SEG1, SEG2 and TITLE  on first row 
and SEG1, SEG24 and JOB on second row.

Each Segment can be in each dataframe such as Df1, df2, df3...ect because I will insert these dataframe to sql server

Please help me

Here is what i am expecting the out put on

```
df1: SEG1 <br>
index   0   1   2   3      <br>
1   SEG1    CA  90025   34 <br>
2   SEG1    NV  90567   50 <br>

df2 : SEG2<br>
index   0   1   2   3   <br>
1   SEG2    2   3   10150<br>


df3 :  TITLE<br>
index           0          1    <br>
1               TITLE       Test    <br>

df4 :  SEG24<br>
index     0     1     2   3 <br>
2      SEG24    4   5   54678 <br>

df5 : JOB<br>
index     0     1  <br>
2      JOB     None
```

Comment: You want to split the columns of this dataframe into three separate dataframes in the structure given, is that right?

Comment: yes. because they are subset of each table

Answer (score 0):

You can split by `~`, then by `|`, so that doesn't matter how many values there are for splitting, as long as the delimiter values starts with `~` (not a problem if the first one does not start with `~`):

```py
s = df.ds_value.apply(lambda x: [x.strip('|') for x in x.split('~')])
dfs = [s.str[i].str.split('|', expand=True) for i in range(len(s[0]))]

# Set the original index for each dataframe
for d in dfs:
    d.index = df.index
```

Output of `dfs` (list of dataframes):

```
[
           0   1      2   3
 index                     
 1      SEG1  CA  90025  34
 2      SEG1  NV  90567  50,

           0  1  2      3
 index                   
 1      SEG2  2  3  10150
 2      SEG2  4  5  54678,

            0     1
 index             
 1      TITLE  Test
 2      TITLE  None
]
```

---

**Explanation:**

In the first line of this code, you'll get a series of elements split by `~` (also removing unnecessary end pipes with `strip`):

```
0    [SEG1|CA|90025|34, SEG2|2|3|10150, TITLE|Test]
1    [SEG1|NV|90567|50, SEG2|4|5|54678, TITLE|None]
Name: ds_value, dtype: object
```

In the second line, we loop trough each group that will create the new dataframes, and expand the values into multiple columns by splitting the pipes. In this step, I've considered that the pattern is consistent across values (same amount of items), otherwise it may fail.

Finally, we put back the original index for all dataframes of the list.

Comment: Thank you for examples. it works                                                                               
 filename = r'C:\sample.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(filename,error_bad_lines=False, names = ['ds_value']) 
s = df.ds_value.apply(lambda x: [x.strip('|') for x in x.split('~')])
dfs = [s.str[i].str.split('|', expand=True) for i in range(len(s[0]))]                                                 # Set the original index for each dataframe
# for d in dfs:
#     d.index = df[index]

Comment: If it worked for you, consider [upvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/887114) and [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/887114) the answer.

Comment: these lines give me an errors                                                                                            
 for d in dfs:
    d.index = df['index']

Comment: Which error? Please paste the error message here.

Comment: since dfs is the list how can i add those dfs into 3 tables in sql

Comment: here is error name 'index' is not defined

Comment: I thought `index` was a separate column. I just updated the answer (changed from `d.index = df['index']` to `d.index = df.index`.

Comment: You can also use `df1,df2,df3 = dfs` and `df1.to_sql(...)` of `dfs[0].to_sql(...)` for adding these to SQL tables.

Comment: it does not work for me i don't see anything after i have these lines
for d in dfs:
    d.index = df.index
    print(dfs[1])
How do i seperate df1 , df2, df0 from dfs? i am new in python

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am sorry i was not clear what i was looking for. and I updated the post with clarification.